# How to switch a project built on Visual studio 2010 from dynamic to static?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have recently started using Visual studio 2010 ,so I'm unaware of its various options.
I have created a project and in the application wizard at the beginning,I had checked the box that said Dynamic Libraries.

Now I need to Statically link the same project to make it portable.Please help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In the solution explorer, find the project in question, right click it and select **Properties**.
2. The default selection in the left sidebar should be **Configuration Property** -> **General**; if it's not, select that.
3. In the main section, under **Project Defaults**, set the Configuration Type dropdown to **Static Library (.lib)**.

Comment: Changing the Configuration type to (.lib) prompted an error. However just below that I found an option saying "Use of MFC: ".So I changed that to Static and it worked. Thanks for guiding me to the configuration manager. +1 because it helped me partially. :)